# npm run production: Error: Cannot find module './Webpack4Cache'

Tags: npm, webpack

I keep on getting this error every time I try to run `npm run production` on the freshly deployed laravel project:

> Error: Cannot find module './Webpack4Cache'

I'm deploying to Ubuntu droplet - any idea how to resolve this issue?

CPU usage also goes over 100% when this npm script is running.

Comment: I got that error after upgrading `eslint` to version 7. Going back to 6 fixed the issue.